# CX_freeze executable will not work. _tkinter DLL load failed

Tags: python, tkinter, cx-freeze

I have the same problem as many other questions, but found no solution working yet. This is on Windows 10 64 bit, Python 3.6 32 bit.

I have tried uninstalling several times, 64 bit Python, various combinations of paths and variables in the setup file.

I do find it confusing that the traceback from the exe file refers to filepaths in my Python folder, not the build folder where the executable resides. I would have thought that this exe should now be "innocent" of the existence of the python folder?

**Output from exe file**

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 14, in run
    module.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 26, in run
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "main3.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\appJar\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from appJar.appjar import gui
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\appJar\appjar.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tkinter import *
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

**My setup file for cx_freeze -**

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\tcl\tk8.6'

build_exe_options={
"includes": [],
"packages": ["os","tkinter"],
"include_files" : [r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\DLLs\tcl86t.dll',
r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\DLLs\tk86t.dll']
}

setup(name = "main" ,
      version = "0.1" ,
      description = "" ,
      options={"build.exe":build_exe_options},
      executables = [Executable("main3.py", base=None, targetName="hexml.exe")])
```

Comment: From the official close reasons: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself_. A corollary of this is that code should be added to questions, rather than offered from an external file locker. Are you able to add this information to the question, for the benefit of future readers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer at last. The lines in the setup file to include the files `tcl86t.dll` and `tk86t.dll` weren't doing their job for some reason. Must be some error in the path formatting.

What worked was copying them manually from the `Python\Dlls` folder and pasting them into the `exe.win` folder where the new executable resides.

I subsequently discovered [here](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issues/155/required-environment-variables-tcl_library) a setup.py script that gets the correct paths. V happy now.

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os
import sys

PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')

options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'include_files':[
            os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll'),
            os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll'),
         ],
    },
}

setup(name = "main" ,
      version = "0.1" ,
      description = "" ,
      options=options,
      executables = [Executable("main3.py", base=None, targetName="hexml.exe")])
```

Comment: This is much better than copying the dlls directly to the exe location, which is the suggestions in many Q&As similar to this question.

Comment: what the hell? i've did this before this problem. still same error